# Bamboo Maven Glassfish Deploy

Tags: maven, glassfish, maven-3, bamboo, glassfish-4

I've been trying to set up continuous integration and deployment for a Java EE application.
Continuous integration is working however the deployment always fail.

I tried 3 things in the maven parameter ${local.glassfish.passfile}:

1. path to domain-password
2. path to.gfclient/pass
3. password string

One last thing I tried was:

  hardcoded value inside pom.xml

Ear pom.xml configuration:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<configuration>
<glassfishDirectory>${local.glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
<user>${local.glassfish.user}</user>
<passwordFile>${local.glassfish.passfile}</passwordFile>
<domain>
<name>${local.glassfish.domain}</name>
<adminPort>${local.glassfish.adminPort}</adminPort>
<httpPort>${local.glassfish.httpPort}</httpPort>
</domain>
<components>
<component>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<artifact>target/${project.build.finalName}.ear</artifact>
</component>
</components>
<debug>true</debug>
<terse>false</terse>
<echo>true</echo>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Running mvn glassfish:deploy inside the ear folder via the terminal successfully deploys the ear artefact to the server.

Bamboo Error log:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ear 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:undeploy (default-cli) @ ear ---
[INFO] Deprecated syntax, instead use:
[INFO] asadmin --echo --terse=false --interactive=false --user admin --passwordfile /home/guest/.gfclient/pass --host localhost --port 55004 undeploy [options] ...
[INFO] asadmin --host localhost --port 55004 --user admin --passwordfile /home/guest/.gfclient/pass --interactive=false --echo=true --terse=false undeploy --keepreposdir=false --isredeploy=false --cascade=false --_ignorecascade=false --_classicstyle=false ear
[INFO] Command undeploy failed.
[ERROR] Authentication failed for user: admin
[ERROR] (Usually, this means invalid user name and/or password)
[ERROR] Undeployment of ear failed.
[ERROR] For more detail on what might be causing the problem try running maven with the --debug option 
[ERROR] or setting the maven-glassfish-plugin "echo" property to "true".
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.699 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-03-06T17:39:50+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.glassfish.maven.plugin:maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:undeploy (default-cli) on project ear: Undeployment of ear failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Failing task since return code of [/home/guest/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn glassfish:undeploy] was 1 while expected 0
Finished task 'Maven Glassfish Undeploy'
```

Note that I ran the "asadmin login" command after I changed the admin password in order to update the pass file.

```
guest@foo:~$ asadmin --port 55004 login
Enter admin user name [Enter to accept default]> admin
Enter admin password>
Admin login information for host [localhost] and port [55004] is being overwritten with credentials provided. This is because the --savelogin option was used during create-domain command.
Login information relevant to admin user name [admin] for host [localhost] and admin port [55004] stored at [/home/guest/.gfclient/pass] successfully.
Make sure that this file remains protected. Information stored in this file will be used by administration commands to manage associated domain.
Command login executed successfully.
```

Also, Glassfish version is 4.0, Maven version is 3.2.1.

Comment: have you tried setting the user/password in the maven config file? see {maven.home}/conf/settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the asadmin login command you don't need to specify the user and password in the undeploy and deploy command as it will use the credentials that you've set using the login command.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Bamboo plugin that allows to deploy an war file to Glassfish Application Server.
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219234/tasks-for-glassfish-server